# Are "Where can I find XXX?" questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

Are questions that ask for a link to a specific type of model, STL file, or object file, such as this example, [Where can I find an object file ir mesh file for a cilantro plant with thick exagerated cartoonish leaves?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/q/20994/4762), on-topic?

IMHO, whilst I am not against such questions, I feel that these types of questions are rather unlikely to be *particularly* useful for other members of the community - they seem to have a "one-shot" type of appeal, which serve a unique set of circumstances that are unlikely to be encountered by others, or elsewhere - if that makes sense...

Usually the answer is "Look on Thingiverse (or a similar repository)", or a link to a particular page on such a site.

Admittedly, these types of questions aren't very frequent and don't *really* pose much of a problem (at the moment).

What do people think?

---

If this is a duplicate, or a similar type of question has been asked previously, then kindly link to the meta question in the comments.

Comment: This is very similar to the "Where do I find this scripture?" over on Bible Hermeneutics/Christianity which **are** considered off-topic. While doing a search should yield what the user is looking for sometimes the individual has tried looking but without success. If the question was to show some kind of "research" then I would say it could be a viable question, otherwise, it's just a "do my homework" question.

Answer (score 1):

### Those are, in its core, *Recommendation Questions*

Unless it is a very specific resource (e.g. "I need the handbook for printer X" or "original Firmware for printer Y"), requests for a general file resource are basically asking "Recommend me a 3D file site!". There is no best answer there, so they are recommendation and shopping questions - and off topic on almost all stacks. And [shopping is a nono on the Stack.](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)